# How to tag questions correctly

Tags: discussion, tags

From time to time I find that people edit tags and remove generic tag when more specific one is also present.

Last example I saw was a question about mysql SQL query with two tags `sql` and `mysql`. Someone edited the question and removed `sql` tag with a description as follows:

> The 'sql' tag is not necessary when a database specific tag is
>   provided. The database specific tag always supersedes the 'sql' tag.

Is removing generic tags when more specific tag is present is the correct approach?

I always thought that having more tags (generic and more specific ones) will in most cases improve search results - what SO is all about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that tag removal is not necessarily appropriate.  MySQL is database, while SQL is a language.  They can certainly be together on a question, and help those searching for SQL answers, who don't care about the database used.

Having said that, there are times when you might not need both the specific and the general tags, even when the specific is a proper subset of the general.  For example, some questions should have both the [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) and [excel-2007](/questions/tagged/excel-2007) tags on them to let people know the OPs specific environment, but still bring those answerers (and future searchers) who search on Excel to that question.

There isn't a line that can always be drawn, and it should be done on a case-by-case basis, based on the contents of the question.